# SimpleGUIApplication in scala 2.10.1

Tags: swing, scala

I'm reading *Programming in Scala* and there is an example GUI program, which extends from class `SimpleGUIApplication`. But I don't see it in my scala library.I think it's removed from 2.10.1.

What is a replacement for `SimpleGUIApplication` in scala 2.10.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found answer in [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/swing/SimpleGUIApplication.html):

`@deprecated Since version 2.8.0 Use SimpleSwingApplication instead`

Comment: And Swing is deprecated too. Take a look at JavaFX2 (and ScalaFX, which provides a nice Scala API for JavaFX2) instead.

Comment: Any proof link please ? I don't see it's deprecated. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication

Comment: it's not the class (rather Swing itself) that's deprecated, and deprecated may not be the correct word to use - swing will still be supported for the foreseeable future, but it won't be developed further.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6

Comment: Swing is not deprecated. You may not like it, and it's not as new and shiny as JavaFX, but it's a perfectly fine platform.